# Upgrading ram causes deadly fault?

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

First of all sorry about my English, I'm not native. Here's my thing: 
I got 1 Asus laptop about 1 year ago. It has 2gb of ram and therefore it's kind of slow. So 2 months ago I decided to upgrade my RAM. I bought a 2gb ram stick of a different model put it into my laptop. At first, it worked just fine and my laptop became faster. But 1 month ago,  I couldn't start my laptop. I took it to asus's service for repairing. They told me the mainboard is broken down and got me another one.

After chaging the main board it worked well until yesterday, it went down again when I was playing NFS. Everything was down, even the charging light. And nothing happens when I press the power button.

So is there any one can help me please?  Is it problem with my extra ram? What should I do now, remove the extra ram or use only 1 ram with 4gb?

For more information, I'm using Asus k45vd. Sorry again, my English is not good.

Comment: I seriously doubt it's the memory.

Comment: I think so too, but I'm not sure. What do you think I sshould do?

Comment: Nothing happening when you press the power button implies that there is a problem with your power supply. Are you sure everything is plugged in properly? As it is there is not enough info here to do more than guess, so I suspect this question will ne closed.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the power supply. Everything was plugged properly. I'm really sorry because I can't express it very well in English

Comment: is their any lights lit on the laptop saying its getting power? If nothing, then its probably the power supply or a bad connection to the laptop.

Comment: No light lit. I'm not sure what the problem is. But it worked just fine until I install the extra ram. Should I keep it or something?

Comment: if its not getting power it doesn't matter if you take out all the memory.

Comment: I mean after repairing it. Because the memory can be the reason for all of these problems.

Comment: A computer/laptop will boot (turn on) with good, bad or NO memory. Your power supply could have fudged your first main board, and might be doing the same thing again. When you got it repaired (mainboard) I am sure they turned it and made sure it was running before you got it back. So if no power it has to be only 3 things: 1) electric outlet 2) powersupply 3) connection to laptop

Comment: So if you are saying it's the power supply, can you think of any reason led to this?  The battery is still in a laptop and I also connect it to a power source when I use it.